# How to add 14 days to value of variable?

Tags: python, django

I use factory boy, this is my factories:

```
class ConFactory(factory.Factory):
    FACTORY_FOR = Con

    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    category = '1'
    number = '12345678'
    time_start = factory.Sequence(lambda n:(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=n)).date(), int)
    time_end = factory.Sequence(lambda n:(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=n+100)).date(), int)
    reminder = datetime.now()
```

How to set `reminder` to `time_start` + 14days

`reminder` = `time_start + 14 days`

Answer (score 0):

```
 from datetime import timedelta
 reminder = datetime.now() + timedelta(14)
```

However, you can't add `time_start` in the initialisation, so you could add a hook in the `save()` function:

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     if self.time_start:
         self.reminder = self.time_start + timedelta(14)
     super(ConFactory, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you've not overridden a `model` attribute before, there is more information [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods).

Comment: It can be done easier and cleaner than that. Please, have a look at my answer....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an attribute value based on other attribute value, you need to use `Lazy Attributes`.

In your case, yo should import timedelta from datetime and put this line in your factory:

```
reminder = factory.LazyAttribute(
    lambda con_factory: con_factory.time_start + timedelta(14)
)
```

For more information, you can read [this](https://github.com/dnerdy/factory_boy#lazy-attributes)